# Android - Bottom Navigation Menu change icon image

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, bottomnavigationview

I need to change the icon menu of the bottom navigation tab when selected. I found the way to change image when selected using `item.setIcon(R.drawable.latest_icon_sel_green);` however, now I need to change the image when it deselected. How could I do this?

```
navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_latest:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        item.setIcon(R.drawable.latest_icon_sel_green);

                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_news:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                        item.setIcon(R.drawable.news_icon_sel_green);

                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_user:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                        item.setIcon(R.drawable.user_icon_sel_green);

                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_upload:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                        item.setIcon(R.drawable.upload_icon_sel_green);

                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_share:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
                        item.setIcon(R.drawable.share_icon_sel_green);

                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create custom drawable using xml like below and give to your navigation item it will take care no need to setIcon when selected,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/share_icon_sel_green"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/share_icon_unsel_green"/>
</selector>
```